# Prevent 'Confirm Navigation' alert with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I've got a button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt15 send-emails" name="SendEmails" value="true">Send Emails</button>
```

And a method:

```
$('.send-emails').click(function (e) {
        // build data and other stuff
        $.post('/leads/sendemails', data, function (data, status, xhr) {
            alert('Emails have successfully been queued for sending.');
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            window.location.href = '/Leads/Lead/' +  @Model.LeadID;
    }, 'json');
});
```

Even with `window.onbeforeunload = null;` I still get the popup warning:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please try this: `$(window).unbind();`

Comment: That worked!  List it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is following:

```
$(window).unbind();
```

This will remove the `onbeforeunload` event just before redirect the browser to a new page using `location.href`.

Comment: This not solving my problem. :(
Is there any other solution for this problem??

Comment: This worked for me at first, then didn't work subsequently. I solved the problem by setting `onbeforeundload = function(){}`

Comment: @Femtosecond, you can add a answer for this in order to help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable to check before redirecting to the page like this. Have a string variable to hold `href` which you need to redirect and redirect it before statement

```
(function($){
    var dontSubmit = false,
        $form = $('form#my-form');

    // Prevent the trigger a false submission on link click
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        dontSubmit = true;
        $form.trigger('submit');
    });

    $form.on('submit', function(event){
        if (dontSubmit) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // Continue on as normal
    });
})(jQuery);
```